# Etymology of vimentin

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, etymology, cytoskeleton

What is the etymology of the intermediate filament , Vimentin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC336257/pdf/pnas00669-0408.pdf) paper:

> From the Latin word vimentum, used to describe arrays of flexible rods,both ordered ones (e.g.,latices,filigres,and wicker-work) and non-ordered ones (e.g.,brushwood).

Vimentin:

[image: Vimentin]

Filigree art:

[image: Filigree art]